# Uploading images in Facebook Pages on an external server

Tags: facebook, facebook-pages, images

Are there any alternatives to where I can upload the images to a Facebook Page instead of directly to the Facebook servers?

I notice on the Facebook Pages of Dell, US Cellular, and the Gap, that they load all of their images on one of their web servers. I was hoping to upload photos and then hide the gallery. But I couldn't find anything like that.

I have access to someone's Facebook fan page but not to their webserver so it would be extra work to email someone who does have access the photos and have them upload them to their web server.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible unless you use a custom Facebook Tab. All photos shown in the Photo galleries are stored on Facebook.